# Printing sum of non abundant numbers in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

This is a Project Euler Problem 23: Non-abundant Sums.

> A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.
>
> A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.
>
> As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.
>
> Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

Here the `sumOfPD` function returns the sum of proper divisors.

I wrote the following code which doesn't work.

```
sumOfPD :: Integral a => a -> a 
sumOfPD x = sum([y | y <- [1..x], rem x y == 0]) - x

main = do
 print (sum ([x + y | x <- [1..], y <- [1..], x + y < 28124, sumOfPD x <= x, sumOfPD y <= y]))
```

I'm new to Haskell. Please help me resolve error.

Comment: Please type in the text in the body of your question. Images of text are inaccessible to many people and to all search engines.

Comment: *If you come across an error post its  text (post, post); if you come across an error post its text (post, post); if you come across an error, and it's making nothing clearer, if you come across an error post its text.* Always add error messages to your question. Otherwise it's like asking for a code review without code.

Comment: Please add the rest of the necessary text and remove the image, which will then be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. One is largely mathematical and one is largely about Haskell semantics. Both stem from a lack of care and clarity of thought; you should think more carefully and slowly about how to write a program which does less work to get to the answer. I'm not going to write down any solution or correct version (indeed project Euler discourages sharing solutions) as that won't help you and it won't help anyone who comes across this by google.

In your sum in `main` you're counting some numbers multiple times. For example $1+2+4+5+10=21>20$ so 20 is abundant. Your list includes $32=12+20=20+12$ at least twice. Note `[32,32] /= [32]`. Also note that this isn't just an issue with counting $x+y$ and $y+x$, there might be some numbers which are the sum of two ambiguous in two (non-trivially) different ways.

Due to the nature of list comprehensions in Haskell, in `main`, `x` will only ever take a value of `1` as the values considered are `(x,y)=(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),...` and then each of those values is tested. There is a point after which all values are rejected as `x+y>=28124` but you never move on to the next `x` value. Indeed all values are rejected as `1` is not abundant. Try changing `[1..]` to `[1..n]` where `n` is something you should decide on. Alternatively, change it to a list of abundant numbers up to some limit. Cf `takeWhile` and `filter`